# Android without life cycle?

Tags: android, design-patterns, operating-system

What exactly the benefits of Android Life cycle and as a developer what I lose when there is no life cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a `lifecycle` or state control, either provided by Android or written by yourself
for most people implementing their own `lifecycle` it will make code a disaster.
Try to manage a view just like an activity!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Android life Cycle]

u can gain some knowledge why it is important using this blog Post

http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/applicationLifecycles.html